# Spark Java: find data in Dataset 1 not in Dataset 2

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dataset

I have 2 Dataset - ds1 with 40 columns and ds2 with 10 columns. Both of them have common id column. How do I build a new dataset with data that is in ds1 but not in ds2?

Comment: You mean like a left outer join? Also, please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] to get valid answers. Your question is unclear at this point.

Comment: What is the number of common columns, or is it just the column common_id?

Comment: which cols needed in new dataset? all too vague

Answer (score 0):

Perform a **Left outer join**. You can do something like this (I assume source data in csv format)

```
Dataset<Row> DS1 = spark.read().option("header",true).csv("path of the File");
Dataset<Row> DS2 = spark.read().option("header",true).csv("path of the File");
ArrayList<String> joinColList = new ArrayList<String>();
joinColList.add("CommonId");
Dataset<Row> joinedData = DS1.join(DS2,scala.collection.JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(joinColList),"leftouter");
joinedData.show();
```